# Dropdown showing error on change in Flutter. Can't set state inside onchange callback function

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

[image: showing this error on change]

Showing this error when trying to onChange.
Basically it doesn't allow to set the state.
Using another dropdown alike this that is working fine.

```
class GetCitiesAndRestaurants {
List<Cities> _cities;
List<RestaurantTypes> _restaurantTypes;

List<Cities> get cities => _cities;
List<RestaurantTypes> get restaurantTypes => _restaurantTypes;

GetCitiesAndRestaurants({
  List<Cities> cities, 
  List<RestaurantTypes> restaurantTypes}){
_cities = cities;
_restaurantTypes = restaurantTypes;
}

GetCitiesAndRestaurants.fromJson(dynamic json) {
if (json["cities"] != null) {
  _cities = [];
  json["cities"].forEach((v) {
    _cities.add(Cities.fromJson(v));
  });
}
if (json["restaurantTypes"] != null) {
  _restaurantTypes = [];
  json["restaurantTypes"].forEach((v) {
    _restaurantTypes.add(RestaurantTypes.fromJson(v));
  });
}
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
var map = <String, dynamic>{};
if (_cities != null) {
  map["cities"] = _cities.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
}
if (_restaurantTypes != null) {
  map["restaurantTypes"] = _restaurantTypes.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
}
return map;
}

}

/// id : 1
/// restaurantTypeName : "Arabian"

class RestaurantTypes {
int _id;
String _restaurantTypeName;

int get id => _id;
String get restaurantTypeName => _restaurantTypeName;

RestaurantTypes({
  int id, 
  String restaurantTypeName}){
_id = id;
_restaurantTypeName = restaurantTypeName;
}

RestaurantTypes.fromJson(dynamic json) {
_id = json["id"];
_restaurantTypeName = json["restaurantTypeName"];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
var map = <String, dynamic>{};
map["id"] = _id;
map["restaurantTypeName"] = _restaurantTypeName;
return map;
}

}

class Cities {
int _id;
String _cityName;

int get id => _id;
String get cityName => _cityName;

Cities({
  int id, 
  String cityName}){
_id = id;
_cityName = cityName;
}

Cities.fromJson(dynamic json) {
 _id = json["id"];
_
cityName = json["cityName"];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
var map = <String, dynamic>{};
map["id"] = _id;
map["cityName"] = _cityName;
return map;
}

}
```

This is modal class used to get response from server.
the below same code for generating other list from server is working
But this is not working

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            labelStyle: formMiniStyle,
                                            labelText: 'City',
                                          ),
                                          value: _selectedCity,
                                          onChanged: (newValue)  {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _selectedCity = newValue;
                                            });

                                          },
                                          items: fromServer.data.cities.map((city) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                              child: Text(city.cityName),
                                              value: city.cityName,
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        )
```

The above code generates the particular error on change the dropdown value

```
class CreateBranch extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
_CreateBranchState createState() => _CreateBranchState();
}

class _CreateBranchState extends State<CreateBranch> {
Future<GetCitiesAndRestaurants> getCitiesAndRestaurants;
 var _selectedCity;


 Future<GetCitiesAndRestaurants> fetchCitiesAndRestaurants() async {
 //print(token);
 Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'text/plain',
  "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
  };

  final response = await http.post(
    "${BaseUrl}",
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonEncode({}) //requesting to post empty json
  );

   print(response.statusCode);
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   return GetCitiesAndRestaurants.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
   }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   getCitiesAndRestaurants = fetchCitiesAndRestaurants();
  }  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder<GetCitiesAndRestaurants>(
                  future: getCitiesAndRestaurants,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, fromServer) {
                    if(fromServer.hasData){
                      return Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                        //color: Colors.grey[200],
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, right: 25, left: 25),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("Restaurant profile image"),
                                        Text("Inactive",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Color(0xff35C1F2),
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          width: 50,
                                          height: 50,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                                          child: _image == null
                                              ? Image(
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                              "assets/Bitmap.png",
                                            ),
                                          )
                                              : Image.file(
                                            _image,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Positioned(
                                          left: 60,
                                          bottom: 5,
                                          child: GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: getImage,
                                            child: Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                                child: Icon(
                                                  Icons.edit,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  size: 18,
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        onChanged: (text) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            branchNameEnglish = text;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          isDense: true,
                                          labelStyle: formMiniStyle,
                                          labelText: 'Branch name',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        flex: 1,
                                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            // suffixIconConstraints: ,
                                            labelStyle: formMiniStyle,
                                            labelText: 'Restaurant Type',
                                          ),
                                          value: _restaurantType,
                                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _restaurantType = newValue;
                                            });

                                          },
                                          items: fromServer.data.restaurantTypes.map((restType) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                              onTap: (){
                                                fromServer.data.cities.map((e) => print(e.cityName));
                                                setState(() {
                                                  restaurantId = restType.id;
                                                });
                                              },
                                              child: Text(restType.restaurantTypeName),
                                              value: restType,
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                                child: TextField(
                                  onChanged: (text) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      location = text;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    isDense: true,
                                    labelStyle: formMiniStyle,
                                    labelText: 'Location',
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: openGoogleMap,
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                        )),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 1,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        onChanged: (text) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            landmark = text;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          labelStyle: formMiniStyle,
                                          labelText: 'Landmark',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                    SizedBox(width: 20,),

                                    Expanded(
                                        flex: 1,
                                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            labelStyle: formMiniStyle,
                                            labelText: 'City',
                                          ),
                                          value: _selectedCity,
                                          onChanged: (newValue)  {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _selectedCity = newValue;
                                            });

                                          },
                                          items: fromServer.data.cities.map((city) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                              child: Text(city.cityName),
                                              value: city.cityName,
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        )
                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 50),
                              Column(children: [
                                Text("Please contact Jahezlee for subscription charges",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 13,
                                        color: Color(0xffE35F21),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                SizedBox(height: 20),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    Text("+964 23467581",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            color: Color(0xffE35F21),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    Text("email@jehezlee.com",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 13,
                                            color: Color(0xffE35F21),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ]),
                              LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints){
                                if(constraints.maxWidth > 500){
                                  return SizedBox(height: 100,);
                                }else{
                                  return SizedBox(height: 60,);
                                }
                              }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }else if(fromServer.hasError){
                      return Text("Something Went wrong");
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child: Container(
                          width: 35,
                          height: 35,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color> (kPrimaryColor),
                          )),
                    );
                  },
                ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Can you please post complete code of StatefulWidget where you're using  `DropdownButtonFormField`

Comment: I removed unwanted states here

Comment: Check @Michael Soleman's reply, I think he's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
value: _selectedCity,
onChanged: (newValue)  {
 setState(() {
  _selectedCity = newValue;
  });
},
```

`value=_selectedCity` is where the error is coming from, because `_selectedCity` is null as you didn't initialize it. You must initialize it with a default value so that `value` won't be `null`.

Like this: `var _selectedCity = defaultValue;` otherwise with just `var _selectedCity;`, `_selectedCity` would be `null`.

**Update**

My next guess is, from the error message, it tells you that there is more than one `DropdownMenuItem` that has the same value, so try checking your values again so there are no duplicates.

```
items: fromServer.data.cities.map((city) {
      return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(city.cityName),
           value: city.cityName, // duplicated values here maybe!
            );
         }).toList(),
```

Comment: No everything inside the cityname is unique. Getting only three data as of now. So can easily check duplications

Comment: literally tried all stackoverflow answers nothing worked to me

Comment: the only thing that will help you now is tracing the code, try removing the component that omits the error, and adding it line by line with constant values, also check for every value if it's null replace it with a default value, use the ?? to do that